# passing C# array to C++ vector

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, vector

My C# will call a class method (made in C++) and feed c# array data into this class method, where it accept vector as data container.

It is working when myclass.method1 accept myArrayCpp as array of double in C++. Now  I would like to myArrayCpp be vector.

How could it be done?

Comment: *Now I would like to myArrayCpp be vector.* -- Don't do it, it won't work this way.  Internally within the C++ code, you copy the array to a vector, but that's about it.

Comment: is this via pinvoke? You cannot safely call c++ code via pinvoke, you must write a C wrapper that exposes the functions you need

Comment: @pm100 Really? We link C# to C++ via PInvoke all the time. Well, C++/CLI anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not directly.

Vectors *own* their contents and perform memory management on them. That's not what you want.

You could copy the data from the array into a new vector.

Otherwise, just stick with the pointer arithmetic!

Comment: In C++ part, initially I used array to hold data. now I am facing that input data is big and occupied space in stack overflow. So I need to use vector for data container.